# NixOS: OpenGL drivers missing

Tags: opengl, wayland, nixos

I made a clean installation of NixOS **without X11**.

Then I ran

```
nix-env -i wayland
nix-env -i sway
nix-env -i glu
nix-env -i mesa-noglu
reboot
sway
```

Yet I receive follwing error

```
gbm: failed to open any drive (search paths /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri/i965_dri.so: open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: i965
gbm: failed to open any drive (search paths /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so: open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
gbm: failed to open any drive (search paths /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /run/opengl-driver/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: wrast

[wlc] Failed to init compositor
```

In other words I am missing some opengl drivers, but how am I supposed to get them?

Comment: Not sure about wayland or sway but for OpenGL support you may need to enable `hardware.opengl.enable` and `hardware.opengl.driSupport` options in your configuration.nix. Would seem to work for me when tested in a VM without xserver enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I am running NixOS with Sway and without X11. I managed to recreate your error by commenting out this line in my configuration.nix:

> hardware.opengl.enable = true;

When I reinstated the line Sway worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

When you're dealing with services on NixOS, such as Xorg, wayland, etc, they will not work when installed from `nix-env`. Instead, you need to enable and configure them in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

When you're not sure how to configure a service the best place to start is with the NixOS [manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/).

After that, use the [options](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html) page to get more detailed information about configuration options. For example, if you search for *opengl* you'll see various options you can configure.

Unfortunately, as far as I know wayland is not available as a service on NixOS. So you may have tough time getting it to work.

Typically, a service which depends on packages will have a option where you can specify what that package should be. For example, the fontconfig NixOS module has the option `fonts.fonts` which can be set to a list of font packages. This allows the fontconfig module to set up the fonts correctly. A similar strategy can be used with a Wayland module, whenever that is written.

Comment: That's because Wayland is not a service like Xorg. It doesn't require a daemon, it's a library.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, installing stuff (like mesa) won't change some system properties.  In this particular case, the necessary `/run/opengl-driver*` symlinks are set up on NixOS when starting the `display-manager` service.